# Webkit Causes the chromecast receiver web application to hang

Tags: webkit, chromecast

When I try to use the webkit blur filter in my receiver web application , the chromecast devices hangs after displaying some images(4 to 5 images)

Does it have to do with some limitations with the chromecast chrome os?
are these filters not supported in chromecast yet??

Comment: Some code showing what you have done would be helpful.

Comment: And you need to capture console logs as well.

Comment: @Einar : the only code is I am using a webkit filter like below : 
 -webkit-filter:blur(15px);
If I remove this it works fine

,  
Ali Naddaf :There is nothing different in the console, it just hangs, I want to know is it because of some memory issue in chromecast?
should I avoid using webkit and implement my own filter instead of using webkit-filter?

Comment: Can confirm I'm having this same problem with the following css `filter: blur(50px)`. I'll probably end up going the route of having a service similar to Imgix serve a blurred image instead of using CSS.